# ElementVisitor Annotation FieldElement to value null check not working

Tags: flutter, dart, builder, analyzer

I am working with `Code Generation` and trying to get some `values` from a `AnnotaedClass`.

I am able to get the `elements` with the `visitFieldElement` but I can not cast them to their actual values...

This is the `Class` where I want to get the `fields` **with their actual `Type`**:

```
@generateTranslation
class LocaleConfiguration {
  static const String baseLanguageCode = 'de';

  static const List<String> supportedLanguageCodes = [
    'de',
    'en',
    'es',
  ];
}
```

This is my `visitFieldElement`:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> fields = <dynamic, dynamic>{};

  @override
  dynamic visitFieldElement(FieldElement element) {
    final type = element.type.toString().replaceAll('*', '');

    final valueRaw = element.computeConstantValue();

    if (valueRaw.toStringValue() != null) {
      fields[type] = valueRaw.toStringValue();
    }
    if (valueRaw.toListValue() != null) {
      fields[type] = valueRaw.toListValue();
    }

    fields[type] = valueRaw;
  }
```

**Problem**

The `!= null` checks are never actually `true`.

If I simply call `toStringValue` for all elements, the `value` of the `supportedLanguageCodes` is `null` and if I call `toListValue` on all elements, the `value` of `baseLangugeCode` is `null`...

What am I missing here?  Why are the `null checks` not working correctly?

Let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: simply use `print` to see what those values really are, and you will find the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
  @override
  dynamic visitFieldElement(FieldElement element) {
    final type = element.type.toString().replaceAll('*', '');

    final valueRaw = element.computeConstantValue();

    if (valueRaw.toStringValue() != null) {
      fields[type] = valueRaw.toStringValue();
    }
    if (valueRaw.toListValue() != null) {
      fields[type] = valueRaw.toListValue();
    }

    fields[type] = valueRaw;
  }
```

should be

```
  @override
  dynamic visitFieldElement(FieldElement element) {
    final type = element.type.toString().replaceAll('*', '');

    final valueRaw = element.computeConstantValue();

    if (valueRaw.toStringValue() != null) {
      fields[type] = valueRaw.toStringValue();
    } else if (valueRaw.toListValue() != null) {
      fields[type] = valueRaw.toListValue();
    } else {
      fields[type] = valueRaw;
    }
  }
```